# Ubuntu hibernation performance

Tags: ubuntu, hibernate

Can I do something with it? Seriously, it is faster to boot Ubuntu from scratch and open all the applications than restore from hibernation.

Comment: This is probably so irrelevant that you can ignore it, but on Windows I found hibernate performance negatively affected by disk caching - if I turned it off, hibernate was incredibly slow.

Comment: It's not incredible slow, it as slow as hibernate in Windows XP. But man, Ubuntu loads just so much faster.

Answer (score 3):

I expect a return from hibernation to be slightly costly compared to a straight boot.
The speed of Ubuntu bootup and shutdown is so comfortable that I always choose to shutdown.

However, I can understand the need for hibernation, and also the conditions when one would usually use it -- leading to the related slower restore...

You could try [**`TuxOnIce`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TuxOnIce)

> **TuxOnIce** (formerly known as Suspend2) is an implementation of the suspend-to-disk (or hibernate) feature which is available as patches for the 2.6 Linux kernel. It was formerly known as 'swsusp'.

UbuntuGeek [article ref](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-tuxonice-in-ubuntu.html),

> Tuxonice is an alternative way to hibernate your machine than the standard ubuntu power manager way. It generally claims to be more configurable and flexible than the standard method, with faster hibernate and resume times.

References: [Wiki](http://wiki.tuxonice.net/) and [HOWTO](http://www.tuxonice.net/HOWTO.html).
Also you may want to [read this](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0905.2/00098.html).

Comment: I came from Windows world and there hibernation is much faster than straight boot :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check your swappiness value. Usually it is left at 60. It should be 10 or 15:

> cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness

You can change it on the fly with

> sudo bash -c "echo  -e 10 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness"

and make it stick with

> sudo bash -c "echo 'vm.swappiness = 15' >> /etc/sysctl.conf"